# Liquibase syntax for runCommand in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

I’m trying to add liquibase to my project. I need to create a collection along with index and shard keys creation. I'm using the next command in Mongo shell and it works fine:

db.runCommand{customAction: "CreateCollection", collection: "name", offerThroughput: 400, shardKey: "partition_key", indexes: [{key: {_id: 1}, name: "_id_1"}, {key: {partition_key: 1, some_key: 1}, name: "partition_key_1_some_key_1", unique: true}]};

offerThroughput key is specific for CosmosDB which I’m using in my project.

I tried next options:

My configuration:

```
pom.xml:

    <properties>
            <liquibase.version>4.4.0</liquibase.version>
            <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>4.4.0</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
            <liquibase-mongodb.version>4.4.0</liquibase-mongodb.version>
    </properties>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-mongodb.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
     <build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-mongodb</artifactId>
                            <version>${liquibase-mongodb.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
                            <version>4.2.3</version>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </build>
```

According to the documentation(https://github.com/alexandru-slobodcicov/liquibase-mongodb#implemented-changes) we can use "runCommand".
Also, I found an example(https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb/tree/main/src/test/resources/liquibase/ext) and tried to use it(changelog.run-command.test.xml):

```
 <changeSet id="1" author="alex">

        <ext:runCommand>

            <ext:command>
                { buildInfo: 1 }
            </ext:command>

        </ext:runCommand>

    </changeSet>
```

I tried to run liquibase with the next changelog file configuration:
db.changelog-master.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.3.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="author">

            <ext:runCommand>
                <ext:command>
                    <![CDATA[ {customAction: "CreateCollection", collection: "name", offerThroughput: 400, shardKey: "partition_key", indexes: [{key: {_id: 1}, name: "_id_1"}, {key: {partition_key: 1, some_key: 1}, name: "partition_key_1_some_key_1", unique: true}]}]]>
                </ext:command>
            </ext:runCommand>

    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

And the next one:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.3.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="author">

            <ext:runCommand>
                <ext:command>
                    {customAction: "CreateCollection", collection: "name", offerThroughput: 400, shardKey: "partition_key", indexes: [{key: {_id: 1}, name: "_id_1"}, {key: {partition_key: 1, some_key: 1}, name: "partition_key_1_some_key_1", unique: true}]}
                </ext:command>
            </ext:runCommand>

    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

All my attempts failed. I didn't find any example with such a command. I would appreciate it very much if somebody could share the correct syntax to run such a command for liquibase on MongoDB.

Answer (score -2):

I see you have the same question posted in the liquibase forum. Also, your post seems to be active. I would suggest to keep an eye on the liquibase forum [post](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/syntax-for-runcommand-for-mongodb/5708/5)